# How do you use groups in XCode?

Tags: xcode

I started using groups in Xcode the same way I use packages in Java or namespaces in C++, even though groups have no effect on the language.

Then I discovered Smart Groups and realised that it's sort of pointless to have my code neatly organised in "folders".

Do you use groups? If so, how and why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Groups are just an organisational tool, and you can use them in the way that is most logical to you.

Often developers will put their Model, View and Controller classes in separate groups. You might also want to put header files in their own group to reduce clutter.

I create a group for "utility" classes like categories, and a group for each main component of the application, for instance "Inspector" or "Preview". In those groups, the classes are further organised into Model, View and Controller groups.

It's up to you though, just do whatever feels natural.

Comment: There are already smartgroups for header and implementation files.

Comment: as an aside for groups... they are 90% just organizational.  but i bleieve there is an option for xcode to create the directory structure too when you drag files in.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using unit tests, these can go in their own group as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, I use groups for Model/View/Controller and for unit testing.

I use groups also for Doxygen documentation (`doxyfile` configuration file and `.dot` pictures) and for embedded applications such as `ffmpeg` source code.

Answer (score 0):

In the Info window for a group, you can set the group to correspond to a real folder on disk. Then, when you create files in your project by right-clicking on the group and choosing “Add New File”, Xcode will create the files in the group's folder.

I do this for my test case classes. You can do it for any set of classes you want to keep both in their own group and in their own folder.

Answer (score 0):

Groups are simple.

The only use I can find for them is bypassing the 10-object limit.

Ex:

VStack {

```
Group {
    
    Text("Hello 1")
    Text("Hello 2")
    Text("Hello 3")
    Text("Hello 4")
    Text("Hello 5")
    
}

Group {

    Text("Hello 6")
    Text("Hello 7")
    Text("Hello 8")
    Text("Hello 9")
    Text("Hello 10")
    Text("Hello 11")
}
```

}